# How do I deserialize JSON correctly in C#

Tags: c#, system.web

I am trying to deserialize the Supreme New York JSON but I am getting an error.

I used `json2csharp.com` to convert the Json into classes.

Then I summarised them all into one called `items`

```
namespace SUPBOTTESTING
{
    public class items
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public string image_url_hi { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public int sale_price { get; set; }
        public bool new_item { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
        public string category_name { get; set; }
        public int price_euro { get; set; }
        public int sale_price_euro { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace SUPBOTTESTING
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            {
                string shop_json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json");
                JavaScriptSerializer shop_object = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                items[] shirt_stock = shop_object.Deserialize<items[]>(shop_json);
                Console.WriteLine(shirt_stock[1]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Default constructor not found for type SUPBOTTESTING.items[]

Comment: Why did you combine them all? That's not going to work. Generate the class again and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the solution. You have the correct idea but you need to understand the structure of your Json data.

You are `deserializing` it into an array of `Object` whereas your Json data returned itself is not an Array or a List. It contains child nodes that are an array so you need to structure your `Object` accordingly to get a successful breakdown of data.

Here I have used `Newtonsoft` to deserialise the Json data into an Object.

I have tested the code and it returns a list of `Shirts`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var shop_json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json");
     var shirt_stock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockObject>(shop_json);

     // Picking shirts to demonstrate how to display values for all shirts
     var shirts = shirt_stock.products_and_categories.Shirts;
     foreach (var shirt in shirts)
     {
         var shirtBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         shirtBuilder.AppendLine($"Name: {shirt.name}");
         shirtBuilder.AppendLine($"ID: {shirt.id.ToString()}");
         shirtBuilder.AppendLine($"New Item: {shirt.new_item.ToString()}");
         shirtBuilder.AppendLine($"Category Name: {shirt.category_name}");
         Console.WriteLine(shirtBuilder);
     }
}
```

```
public class StockObject
{
    public ProductsCats Products_and_categories { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ProductsCats
{
    public Details[] Shirts { get; set; }
    public Details[] Bags { get; set; }
    public Details[] Accessories { get; set; }
    public Details[] Pants { get; set; }
    public Details[] Jackets { get; set; }
    public Details[] Skates { get; set; }
    public Details[] Hats { get; set;}
    public Details[] Sweatshirts { get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("Tops/Sweaters")]
    public Details[] TopsSweaters { get;set;}
    public Details[] New { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Details
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string image_url_hi { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int sale_price { get; set; }
    public bool new_item { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public int price_euro { get; set; }
    public int sale_price_euro { get; set; }
}
```

You see what I have done here?

So your Json data contains a parent node `products_and_categories` and its child node contains an array of `Shirts` which is what you are after?

`StockObject` class contains the `Parent` property called `Products_and_categories` of type object `ProductsCats`.

`ProductsCats` Object contains the property `Shirts` of type `Details` which is an array and will be used during the `deserialising` process.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Hey, I understand your though and tyvm for your soloution. Though, when I try to run this code I get the output "SUPBOTTY.StockObject".

Comment: @AhmedSoliman I have edited my answer please see now and let me know if it helps you? Please mark it as answer if you are happy with it?

Comment: Just to note in the amend I have only displayed the `Shirts` to show you how to display the values. Similar will apply for others however you will need to think of a strategy how to efficiently display the data. :)

Comment: Thank you for being helpful, tried the code but I'm getting an error saying 's' doesn't exist in the current context in the line "shirtBuilder.AppendLine($"Name: {s.name}");"

Comment: Sorry Just fixed there :)

Comment: This worked really good! Marked as solution, you are my superhero <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199644/discussion-between-ahmed-soliman-and-kjsr).

Answer (score 2):

Well you do not need to specify a default constructor. What is wrong is, i think you didn't check the json data properly. Because your `items` class is not in the first level of json. You need to create a couple of classes to be more accurate on deserializing.

First of all you need to know that this `json` file has a lot of bad-smells and bad-practices on it.

Note that you need to install `Newtonsoft.Json` before going further. It is much more convenient way to deserialize a json into C# classes.

Yet, i wrote a proper way of deserializing it:

```
public class BaseItem
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image_url { get; set; }
    public string Image_url_hi { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Sale_price { get; set; }
    public bool New_item { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Category_name { get; set; }
    public int Price_euro { get; set; }
    public int Sale_price_euro { get; set; }
}
public class Shirt : BaseItem { }
public class Bag : BaseItem { }
public class Accessory : BaseItem { }
public class Pant : BaseItem { }
public class Jacket : BaseItem { }
public class Skate : BaseItem { }
public class Hat : BaseItem { }
public class Sweatshirt : BaseItem { }
public class TopsSweater : BaseItem { }
public class New : BaseItem { }
public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> Unique_image_url_prefixes { get; set; }
    public ProductsAndCategories Products_and_categories { get; set; }
    public string Release_date { get; set; }
    public string Release_week { get; set; }
}
public class ProductsAndCategories
{
    public List<Shirt> Shirts { get; set; }
    public List<Bag> Bags { get; set; }
    public List<Accessory> Accessories { get; set; }
    public List<Pant> Pants { get; set; }
    public List<Jacket> Jackets { get; set; }
    public List<Skate> Skate { get; set; }
    public List<Hat> Hats { get; set; }
    public List<Sweatshirt> Sweatshirts { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Tops/Sweaters")]
    public List<TopsSweater> TopsSweaters { get; set; }
    public List<New> New { get; set; }
}
```

First of all, all of your items are have the same properties on them, yet, they all marked as different properties. So that, i created a `BaseItem` class and other empty classes which are inherited from that.

Also you need other 2 classes -which are `RootObject` and `ProductsAndCategories`- to provide data on them. Note that there is a `JsonProperty("blabla")` on the `TopsSweaters` property. Because, in json file it is `Tops/Sweaters`, and you can not use that name on a C# property. That is the attribute for using that kind of different property names.

Then you can populate your object like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonData = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json";
        string shopJson = new WebClient().DownloadString(jsonData);
        RootObject shirtStock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(shopJson); //All json data is in this variable
        Console.WriteLine(shirtStock.Products_and_categories.Shirts[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that youre using a class to load the JSON data in, where you should use a struct, alternatively you can also create a constructor that takes no arguments and sets all variables to default values, which is a lot of work so just replace `class` with `struct`:

```
public struct Items
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image_Url { get; set; }
    public string Image_Url_Hi { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Sale_Price { get; set; }
    public bool New_item { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Category_Name { get; set; }
    public int Price_Euro { get; set; }
    public int Sale_Price_Euro { get; set; }
}
```

Also please stick to C# naming conventions, you should be able to do this since most JSON parsers are case insensitive by default.

Some more info: A class doesnt really has a proper default constructor if you dont define one, where as a struct always has a default constructor, so when the JSON parser wants to init your class it cant because a default constructor isnt definded.

Answer (score -1):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string shop_json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json");

        JavaScriptSerializer shop_object = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var shirt_stock = shop_object.Deserialize<NewYarkItems>(shop_json);

        var v = shirt_stock;

    }


public class NewYarkItems
{
    public dynamic unique_image_url_prefixes { get; set; }
    public products_and_categories products_And_Categories { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public string release_week { get; set; }
}

public class products_and_categories
{
    public List<items> Jackets { get; set; }
}


public class items
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string image_url_hi { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int sale_price { get; set; }
    public bool new_item { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public int price_euro { get; set; }
    public int sale_price_euro { get; set; }
}
```